# Excel using COUNTIFS and OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my example the result should be 3 but it shows me 0.
Count, if in

A:A = 1 AND B:B = (3 or 4 or 5).

I was trying something like that but it doesnt work:

=COUNTIFS(A:A; 1; B:B; OR(B=3;B=4;B=5))

[image]

------------------------ EDIT:

Let's say I have one more colum with characters:

[image]

And I want to count only the character with "a".

Comment: Try: =SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,{3,4,5}))

Comment: Since you deleted all your three comments, as you are using german version and not english version, I have posted the german version here as well, `=SUMME(ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;1;B:B;{3.4.5}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use formula like shown below, since commented above:

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,{3,4,5}))
```

---

Or,

• try using `SUMPRODUCT()`

```
SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,{3,4,5}))
```

---

> After OP has edited post:

Alternative versions & required output shown below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,{3,4,5},C:C,"a"))
```

• In German Version:

```
=SUMME(ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;1;B:B;{3.4.5};C:C;"a"))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=SUM((A2:A10=1)*(C2:C10="a")*(B2:B10={3,4,5}))
```

• In German Version:

```
=SUMME((A2:A10=1)*(C2:C10="a")*(B2:B10={3.4.5}))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=SUM(MMULT(--((A2:A10=1)*(C2:C10="a")*(B2:B10={3,4,5})),{1;1;1}))
```

• In German Version:

```
=SUMME(MMULT(--((A2:A10=1)*(C2:C10="a")*(B2:B10={3.4.5}));{1;1;1}))
```

---

Comment: @Yokanishaa in german version it should be `=SUMME(ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;1;B:B;{3.4.5}))`

Comment: It would be =SUMME(ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;1;B:B;{3;4;5})) - but thank you.
I also have characters in other colums which I also have to sort out. Seems like it doesnt work with characters.

Comment: You have posted something and asking something else, we dont know what you have unless, you show us

Comment: I edited, see top pls

Comment: Need to be this then `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,{3,4,5},C:C,"a"))` & in german version `=SUMME(ZÄHLENWENNS(A:A;1;B:B;{3.4.5};C:C;"a"))`

Comment: Perhaps you should not use hardcoding the criteria, instead use cell reference that makes it more dynamic

Comment: Yes, I am using cell references. I have just tried and it works perfectly. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Yokanishaa also you can use only `SUM()` function `=SUMME((A2:A10=1)*(C2:C10="a")*(B2:B10={3.4.5}))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,1,B2:B10,{3,4,5}))`

But I would recommend to "outsource" the criteria for 3,4,5 to an extra range.
Then it is much easier to update the filter if necessary.